# Additional properties in element in the timber framework

Tags: javascript, html, css

The timber framework has additional properties in the standard html-elements such as `<li>`

When validating my final web-page using http://www.validome.org/ these elements are highlighted as errors ("attribute data-image not valid for li element")

```
<li class="tms-slide" data-image>
```

What is this `data-image` and where can I find more information on how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"data-" is an HTML5 attribute that allows for adding custom attributes (This can be anything). So the "data-image" attribute will be a custom attribute implemented in the timber framework. It will not validate (because the validator cannot account for custom data attributes), but it is valid HTML. An explanation of the data attribute can here: [http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/][1]

[1]: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/. Hope that helps.